# Biblatex bibliography section changes chapter name in header

Tags: biblatex, header-footer, koma-script

I'm putting together my thesis, using the Koma script book class and biblatex to create separate reference lists for each chapter. I'm putting the name of the chapter in the header of each left page, using the `chapterprefix=on` option to `scrbook`. I'm also using the `[header=subbibintoc]` option to the `\printbibliography` command to get the bibliography as an unnumbered section in the table of contents. However, from the reference section and through to the end of each chapter, the chapter name in the heading is changed to "Bibliography". How do I get the header to print the chapter name throughout the bibliography section in each chapter?

Using `[header=subbibliography]` almost gives me what I want, except the bibliography does not appear in the table of contents. Using `[header=subbibnumbered]` also almost gets me what I want, except the bibliography is numbered.

I've included a minimal working example below that illustrates my problem. Note that on page two of the compiled document, the header correctly prints the chapter name, while on page 4, it erroneously prints "Bibliography".

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=on]{scrbook}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-comp,
    refsection=chapter,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @misc{A01,
        author = {Author, A.},
        year = {2001},
        title = {Alpha},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Test}

\lipsum \lipsum \lipsum \autocite{A01}.

\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc]

\begin{subappendices}

\section{An appendix}

\lipsum

\end{subappendices}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ORIGINAL ANSWER: While the `refsection=chapter` option will assure that *"all cited works are assigned labels which are local to the environment"* (`biblatex` manual, section 3.6.4), it does not modify the sectioning level of the bibliographies created with `\printbibliography`. Your "reference section" in the MWE is actually an unnumbered *chapter* (the default for the `scrbook` class), as should be obvious from the forced page break. For an unnumbered section, you must issue `\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]` -- this will produce the correct layout, including headers.

UPDATE: (I'm assuming that the problematic header is actually at p. 6 in your MWE, while p. 4 is fine.) You seem to have stumbled upon a bug in the `biblatex` interface to `scrbook`. With this class, `heading=subbibintoc` uses the `\addsec` command which produces an unnumbered section with ToC entry and (with the help of `\markright`) headers. For whatever reason, `biblatex` adds a `\markboth` -- removing this command from the `subbibintoc` definition produces correct headers.

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=on]{scrbook}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-comp,
    refsection=chapter,
]{biblatex}

\defbibheading{subbibintoc}[\refname]{%
  \addsec{#1}%
%   \markboth{#1}{#1}}% DELETED
  }% NEW

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @misc{A01,
        author = {Author, A.},
        year = {2001},
        title = {Alpha},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Test}

\lipsum \lipsum \lipsum \autocite{A01}.

\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc]

\begin{subappendices}

\section{An appendix}

\lipsum

\end{subappendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but your answer made me realize that I did not give a complete description of my problem. In my original files, I had `\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc]`, which for some reason I excluded from the MWE. That puts the bibliography in the TOC, and does not start it on a new page, but it does give me the problem with the header. Your solution causes the bibliography to drop from the TOC. Using `heading=subbibnumbered` solves those two problems, but numbers the bibliography, which I do not want. I've edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: Will you write a bug report?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Maybe pointing Audrey & friends to this question is sufficient.

Comment: @Audrey Please have a look at this question.

Comment: @lockstep: Quick ;-)

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem. I had a feeling it was a bug when I started looking through the `heading`options.